# Is the Visual Studio template file just a regular .zip file or is it something else?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-templates

I'm trying to tweak a project template file exported by Visual Studio's "Export Template" wizard. At first glance this looks like just a garden-variety zip file, but it's not:

1. I can't edit files. If I try to change or delete or replace a file in the zip archive, I get `The Compressed (zipped) Folder is invalid or corrupted.`
2. If I uncompress and recompress the zip file, Visual Studio no longer recognizes it as a template.

Is this something specific to my setup, or is there something non-standard about the zip format used by Visual Studio templates?

---

**Edit** I tried again and actually #2 above isn't true - I can un-zip, edit, and re-zip and VS sees the template. Still stumped as to why I couldn't manipulate the original archive directly, but I'm moving on.

Comment: Try using 7-Zip.  It's a free alternative.

Comment: Nope, it's a plain ZIP archive.  Your zip tool sounds borked.

Comment: I've tried both the built-in Windows zip tool and 7-Zip, on two different machines. They both fail.

Comment: FWIW I've tried this with templates based on a nearly empty project, so it's not anything peculiar about the project itself.

Comment: I too am having the exact symptoms of #2, I have tried standard windows "Send to Zip file" and 7-zip, neither is working.

Comment: look below at JoJo's answer, this is the real issue and solution as to why VS no longer recognizes the file after editing. I wish i would have read it hours ago...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Visual Studio templates use the standard ZIP`ing format.  I've succesfully compressed and uncompressed these files many times in the past.

What ZIP tool are you using?

Comment: I've tried both the built-in Windows zip tool and 7-Zip, on two different machines. They both fail.

Comment: The built in windows zip tool has some incompatibilities.  I have tried zipping things with ziplib and unzipping them with windows zip and it fails.  But winzip will unzip it - not sure where the problem lies

Comment: For others with this issue, see Jojo Lechelt's answer below if the accepted answer does not help.

Answer (score 7):

Solution is here to find: [Exported Project Template from VS2008 but it is corrupted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/268037/exported-project-template-from-vs2008-but-it-is-corrupted)
In short: don't zip the directory, go into the directory, select all files and zip them into an archive.

Comment: dang, i came here specifically to say exactly this answer!
This is the true solution!

Answer (score 1):

I have used Winzip in the past to unzip a template, make changes, then rezip and VS read it and recognized the changes.  This was VS2005 and VS2008